# Java Doesn't Work with Legislative Elections Application

Tags: firefox, java, oracle

It is possible for French citizens living abroad to vote by the internet in this weekend's legislative elections (Elections législatives). The process begins at [this](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/les-francais-a-l-etranger/elections-2012-votez-a-l-etranger/) website. Among the supported operating systems are Ubuntu Linux as indicated [here](http://www.monvotesecurise.votezaletranger.gouv.fr/assistance-technique.html). When I go to vote it tells me Java is not working, (Java : non installé ou la version détectée n'est pas à jour. Votre configuration ne satisfait pas les conditions requises pour pouvoir voter en toute sécurité par internet) even though my Java is up to date.

Comment: Please consider closing some of your questions by selecting the best answer using the checkmark.

Comment: I can only do it two days time

Comment: ObsessiveFOSS means some of your *other* questions, not this one. (Though you should probably accept your answer here once you're able to, as well.) See [this meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) and [this meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1006/how-to-improve-my-accept-rate) and most of all [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/351/what-is-accept-rate-and-why-is-it-important).

Answer (score 2):

The second link covers most of the details needed to solve this problem, but not all. It tells you that Firefox 9,10 or 11 are supported but doesn't tell you how to do it with Firefox 13. It tells you that the Openjdk version of Java is **not** supported, while Oracle Java is,  but it doesn't tell you how to 'activate' Oracle Java if you have both versions installed.

The website makes use of the Java browser plugin, but the version it uses is not supported any more by Ubuntu. So you have to download it from Oracle's website. If you use a version that's too old (< 1.6.0_31) Firefox 13 will not allow you to use it, because of its strong security standards. If you use a version that's too new (> 1.7) you will have certificate problems. Version 1.6.0_32 is recommended and you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u32-downloads-1594646.html).

Once you have it, run these commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod u+x jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin
./jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin
sudo mv jre1.6.0_32 /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin
```

The last command is necessary if you have Openjdk6 already installed.

Restart your browser, cast your vote and after you can remove Java 1.6 with;

```
rm jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_32
```

and

```
 sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

if you need it.

You have until Tuesday midday to cast your vote.